# PHP preg_match to find multiple occurrences

Tags: php, preg-match

What is the correct syntax for a regular expression to find multiple occurrences of the same string with preg_match in PHP?

For example find if the following string occurs TWICE in the following paragraph:

```
$string = "/brown fox jumped [0-9]/";

$paragraph = "The brown fox jumped 1 time over the fence. The green fox did not. Then the brown fox jumped 2 times over the fence"

if (preg_match($string, $paragraph)) {
echo "match found";
}else {
echo "match NOT found";
}
```

Comment: Try with http://www.regex-tester.de/regex.html

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You want to use [`preg_match_all()`](https://www.php.net/preg-match-all). Here is how it would look in your code. The actual function returns the count of items found, but the `$matches` array will hold the results:

```
<?php
$string = "/brown fox jumped [0-9]/";

$paragraph = "The brown fox jumped 1 time over the fence. The green fox did not. Then the brown fox jumped 2 times over the fence";

if (preg_match_all($string, $paragraph, $matches)) {
  echo count($matches[0]) . " matches found";
}else {
  echo "match NOT found";
}
?>
```

Will output:

> 2 matches found

Comment: I am getting warning Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated.

Comment: remove the "&" from "&$matches"