# Finding the first occurrence from a string using regex and PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to find all the unique whole words from a body of text. Currently this is what I am using but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
$textDump = "cat dog monkey cat snake horse"
$wholeWord = "/[\w]*/";
$uniqueWords = (preg_match($wholeWord, $textDump, $matches));
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You want to use [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/preg_match_all). And the result is thrown into the third variable, `$matches`

Comment: you're not capturing anything. try `(\w*)`. Note: no need to use a character class (`[]`) for just a single "character". That's redundant.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP preg\_match to find multiple occurrences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2029976/php-preg-match-to-find-multiple-occurrences)

Answer (score 6):

```
array_unique(
    str_word_count($textDump,1)
);
```

Comment: Is this really what you wanted? It finds all **distinct** words, so "cat dog cat", becomes `[cat,dog]`. It does not find **unique** words, i.e. `[dog]` from "cat dog cat"

Answer (score 2):

You can use str_word_count

```
$textDump = "cat dog monkey cat snake horse";
$uniqueWords = (str_word_count($textDump, 1);
```

Comment: This just puts all of the words in an array: `[cat, dog, monkey, cat, snake, horse]`

Answer (score 1):

Why not achieve this using `explode();` and `array_unique();` in this case?

```
$text = "cat dog monkey cat snake horse";

$foo = explode(" ", $text);
print_r(array_unique($foo));
```

Comment: It seems you have the same misunderstanding as I do. The question asks for word that appear once in the string, not removing duplicate.

Comment: Wouldn't using explode cause issues with punctuation though, since 'hello,' and 'hello' would both register as unique.

Comment: I didn't get the exact question,:)

Answer (score 1):

The answers given so far all assume, that with "find all the unique whole words" you really meant "remove duplicates". Actually your question is not very clear about it, as you don't specify what your desired output is in your example, but I'll take you at your word and provide a solution for "find all the unique whole words".

**This means, for the input:**

```
"cat dog monkey cat snake horse"
```

**You will get the output:**

```
"dog monkey snake horse"
```

Actually, [`str_word_count`](http://php.net/str-word-count) is useful for this too, together with [`array_count_values`](http://php.net/array-count-values), which actually *counts* the different *values*:

```
$wordCount = array_count_values(str_word_count($textDump,1));
```

`$wordCount` is now:

```
array(5) {
  ["cat"]    => int(2)
  ["dog"]    => int(1)
  ["monkey"] => int(1)
  ["snake"]  => int(1)
  ["horse"]  => int(1)
}
```

Next, remove the words with a word count higher than 1 (note, that the actual words are the array keys, so we use `array_keys` to get them:

```
$uniqueWords = array_keys(
    array_filter(
        $wordCount,
        function($count) {
            return $count === 1;
        }
    )
);
```

`$uniqueWords` is now:

```
array(4) {
  [0] => string(3) "dog"
  [1] => string(6) "monkey"
  [2] => string(5) "snake"
  [3] => string(5) "horse"
}
```

**Complete code:**

```
$textDump = "cat dog monkey cat snake horse";
$wordCount = array_count_values(str_word_count($textDump,1));
$uniqueWords = array_keys(
    array_filter(
        $wordCount,
        function($count) {
            return $count === 1;
        }
    )
);
echo join(' ', $uniqueWords);
//dog monkey snake horse
```