# Get all images and all except images with regex

Tags: php, regex

I have an article with text and multiple images in it and need to get just images and just text, separately.

Now I have this code and it just returns last image in article:

```
preg_match('/<img.+src=[\'"](?P<src>.+?)[\'"].*>/i', $article, $img);
```

How to select all images and do reverse for getting just text?

Thank you

Comment: Don't use regex for this, use a DOM parser.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/362536

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP preg\_match to find multiple occurrences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2029976/php-preg-match-to-find-multiple-occurrences)

Comment: python+beautifulsoup? soup.find_all('img')..['src']? soup.text? I can provide more detail if you can give me a sample data and I can write some POC code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the DOM for that:

```
$imgSrc = array();
$txt = '';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($article);

$imgs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');

foreach ($imgs as $img) {
    $imgSrc[] = $img->getAttribute('src');
}

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$textNodes = $xpath->query('//*[not(self::script) and not(self::style)]/text()');
foreach ($textNodes as $textNode) {
    $tmp = trim($textNode->textContent);
    $txt .= (empty($tmp)) ? '' : $tmp . PHP_EOL;

}
```

XPath query details:

`//` means anywhere in the DOM tree
`*` means all tag nodes
`[.....]` defines a condition
`not(self::script)` : the current node must not be a script node
`text()` returns the text node

Comment: Thanks, $imgSrc is working now but $txt not. I am getting $article with mysql select and its processed before its displayed on page, its not already displayed data. Is that a problem or something else?

Comment: just second closing bracket in $textNodes is missing :)

Comment: @Yesian_: indeed, only one suffice.

Answer (score 1):

```
$text = preg_replace('/<img.+src=[\'"](?P<src>.+?)[\'"].*>/i', '', $article);
preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"](?P<src>.+?)[\'"].*>/i', $article, $images);

//use $images and $text
```

Comment: In HTML parsing, you almost never want to use a greedy match `.+`. Use an ungreedy one `.+?`